# How can I check if a string has multiple matching groups that are the same?

Tags: regex

Currently, I am filtering out URL paths using Regex (Python). A couple of the URL paths I have come across are irrelevant and I want to detect URLs that are like this.

For example:

```
/ugrad/honors/index.php/policies/sao/policies/overview/step-1-course-requirements.html
/ugrad/honors/index.php/overview/sao/overview/sao/policies/noodle.html
```

In the examples above, you can see that `policies` and `overview` are repeated both times.

**How can I design a Regex function to detect if there are 2+ matching texts anywhere in a URL path?**

---

I have attempted something like this but I am unsure if it is possible to detect if there is 2+ matching texts anywhere in the string

My attempt:  `\S+(\/.+)\1\S+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture a slash, followed by non-slashes, followed by a slash again. Then repeat anything and backreference the capture group:

```
(\/[^\/]+\/).*\1
```

https://regex101.com/r/ygqRZc/1